# PayPal .NET Integration need current paypal_base.dll file

Tags: paypal

I am trying to get my .net 4.0 based website integration with PayPal Express working.

The code I have utilizes the paypal_base.dll

While this file is referenced in numerous recent support posts on various tech forums, I cannot find any active link to download it anywhere on the web.

The x.com site has had all it links disabled since it was replaced by the  new developer.paypal.com web site.
On this new site, which is not very helpful, it provides download link to Github. The only appropriate SDK DLLs I can find there, are the PayPalCoreSDK.dll, PayPalMerchantSDK.dll and PayPalPermissionSDK.dll - none of which appear to include "CallerServices" or other interfaces my code is expecting.

On their new developer.paypal.com site there is no mention of this commonly referenced paypal_base.dll file!  They dont say it has been depreciated.

The DDL's provided by PayPal do not appear to be compatible with my sample code which is looking for the com.paypal.soap.api

For example "CallerServices" does not appear in any of the  Legacy SDK DLLs supplied by PayPal on their GitHub download site.

The version of the paypal_base.dll I have on hand is 5.6.61.0.  I have seen newer version referenced in various support posts.

The version I have is throwing communication errors. "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I am hoping someone can point me to where I can download the most current version of the paypal_base.dll or point me to which PayPal SDK DLL supports these methods.

Many thanks,
ARF

Answer (score 4):

I have just had this exact problem (we had version 5.6.63.0).
The problem was the dll pointing to the wrong API [Endpoints](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_endpoints).
The code was using the SOAP API whilst the dll was pointing the NVP endpoints (you can look inside the dll and see the XML).

The problem was solved by overriding these in the sites Web.config file.

Add the following to the configSections:
`<section name="paypal" type="com.paypal.sdk.core.ConfigSectionHandler, paypal_base"/>`

Then add the XML block in the paypal_base.dll in a `<paypal></paypal>` section in your web.config file, replacing the links with the ones required from the link above.

XML block from paypal_base.dll:

```
<endpoints>
    <wsdl>
        <environment name="live">
            <port name="PayPalAPI">https://api.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA">https://api-aa.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPI" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA" threetoken="true">https://api-aa-3t.paypal.com/nvp</port>
        </environment>
        <environment name="sandbox">
            <port name="PayPalAPI">https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA">https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPI" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
        </environment>
        <environment name="beta-sandbox">
            <port name="PayPalAPI">https://api.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA">https://api-aa.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPI" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
            <port name="PayPalAPIAA" threetoken="true">https://api-3t.beta-sandbox.paypal.com/nvp</port>
        </environment>        
    </wsdl>
</endpoints>
```

replacing each `/nvp` with `/2.0`

Comment: Many thanks. I will give this a try. Any idea where I can download any recent version of the paypal_base.dll?

Comment: I've not been able to find it, but it's possible the most recent version doesn't fix this issue anyway.
Also updated answer to include the necessary XML.

Comment: bummer. This doesn't work (it may have before, not now)!